# How many ways can you choose a unique element from each set when order is not important?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have $5$ sets, each with $5$ unique elements. I would like to pick one element from each set and the order is irrelevant. How many ways are there?

If the order is important, then it's fairly straight-forward: There's $5\times 5$ options for the first slot, then $4\times 5$  for the second and so on...leading to $5!\times 5$. How do I adjust this number when the order is irrelevant?

Thanks

Edit: Assume all elements are unique and there is no overlap between sets.

Comment: Each set has $5$ distinct elements. Are the $25$ elements (all sets considered) all distinct?

Comment: Yes, let's assume that.

Comment: There are $5$ ways to choose an element from the first set. For each such way, there are $5$ ways to choose an element from the second set,and so on, for a total of $5^5$.

Comment: For the record, your setup is correct for counting if order is important, however you made a mistake in simplifying.  It was $(5\cdot 5)(4\cdot 5)(3\cdot 5)(2\cdot 5)(1\cdot 5) = 5!5^5 \neq 5!\cdot 5$

Comment: Just to note, when the order IS important, you correctly say that there are $5 \times 5$ options for the first slot, etc.,... but then there should be $5! \times 5^5$ total, not $5! \times 5$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you.

And to the others, thanks for correcting that. I still don't completely understand why we use the product and not the sum but I'm sure I will if I stare at it for a bit.

Comment: Oh of course, the multiplication principle.

Comment: @superman65: You are welcome. Finally, to answer your question, to turn your (corrected) answer to one where order does not matter, we divide by $5!$.

Comment: I think that $5^5/5!$